# Populating EXT JS Store in a EXT form Panel

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, extjs

Using ASP.NET MVC action method to return Json to a view in order to display the data in a EXT JS form. I am always getting the "record" value as null in the function everythingLoaded even though i can see the action method is returning the JSON data after the Ext.Create. What i am trying to achieve is populate the firstName and lastName param's passed back from the action method to the textbox inside the panel.  Can you help? Below is the code

->App.JS

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

  //Define Store  
    Ext.define('StudentModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        idProperty: 'Id',
        fields: [
            { name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'firstName', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'lastName', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'birthDate', type: 'date' },
            { name: 'street', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'apartment', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'city', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'state', type: 'string' },
        ],
        validations: [{
            type: 'presence',
            field: 'firstName'
        }]
    });

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'StudentModel',
    storeId: 'StudentStoreId',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/Home/GetStudentSubmissions',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: { callback: everythingLoaded } 
 }
);

function everythingLoaded()
{
    var record = store.getAt(0);                
     //Here record is always null
    Ext.form('MyPanel').getForm().loadRecord(record); 
}

Ext.define('StudentView', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    id: 'MyPanel',
    alias: 'widget.StudentView',
    title: 'Student Information',
    resizable: false,
    collapsible: true,
    store:store,
    bodyPadding: '5',
    buttonAlign: 'center',
    border: false,
    trackResetOnLoad: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        msgTarget: 'side',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        layout: 'hbox',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        width: '100%',
        fieldDefaults: {
            labelAlign: 'top',
            labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold'
        },
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'firstName',
        allowBlank: false
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'lastName',
        allowBlank: false
        }]
    }]        
});

 //Here count is always 0
var i = store.getCount();

Ext.create('widget.StudentView', {
    renderTo: 'studentMasterForm'
});

});
```

-> C# Action Method

```
  public JsonResult GetStudentSubmissions()
    {
        return Json(GetStudents(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public Student GetStudents()
    {
        Student studobj = new Student();

        studobj.Id = 1;
        studobj.firstName = "Aravind";
        studobj.lastName = "R";
        studobj.state = "NJ";
        studobj.street = "Center Grove";
        studobj.birthDate = new DateTime(1989, 6, 6);
        studobj.apartment = "DD8";
        studobj.city = "XYZ";

        return studobj;

    }
}
```

->Student Model Class

public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string apartment { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your c# code returns one object "Student", but it is supposed to return an object which have an *array of students* as its "data" property.

You need to return an object of this type:

```
public class ExtStore
{
    public List<Student> data = new List<Student>();
}
```

this way for example:

```
public ExtStore GetStudents()
{
    Student studobj = new Student();

    studobj.Id = 1;
    studobj.firstName = "Aravind";
    studobj.lastName = "R";
    studobj.state = "NJ";
    studobj.street = "Center Grove";
    studobj.birthDate = new DateTime(1989, 6, 6);
    studobj.apartment = "DD8";
    studobj.city = "XYZ";

    ExtStore exs = new ExtStore();
    exs.data.Add(studobj);

    return exs;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathieu!! Wonder why i din't catch it earlier! That was the reason why the record was always null. Now i am able to see the record value populated. Now i ran into an EXT JS issue: "Ext.form('MyPanel').getForm().loadRecord(record); " is breaking with the exception "0x800a138a - JavaScript runtime error: Function expected"

Comment: Ext.get('MyPanel').loadRecord(record);

Comment: Thanks Mathieu.. It is throwing an exception "Object doesn't support property or method 'loadRecord'". However i tried in a different way.  var formPanel = Ext.create('widget.StudentView'.. & then  formPanel.getForm().loadRecord(record); which worked !! On a different note, Instead of passing a list and using GetAt(0), is there a way to pass an Object Type and populating it's values in the Form Panel? In my case, i only have a row of data..

Comment: You should mark this thread as solved (accepting my answer). And yes there is a way: formPanel.getForm().setValues(yourobject);

Comment: Hi Mathieu, I am trying to achieve the same solution using object type instead of list collection. getForm().setValues seems to be deprecated in version 5. I tried formPanel.getForm().loadRecord(store) but it is not working. However i am able to see the return data from server in store.proxy.reader.rawdata.

Comment: You dont have to use a store if you just want to deal with an object. A store is used to deal with a recordset (a list of row). If you just want to load an object with ExtJs you can use Ext.Ajax.request. 

I looked setValues in API docs it's not marked as deprecated? http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-setValues